# WYSIWYG editor showing html content in frontend?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, wysiwyg

I am adding WYSIWYG editor using the UI component in the magento2 custom module. But when I am adding the data by widget then it is not showing in a proper way. What is the issue?

```xml
*custom_hello_data.xml file in uicomponent.*

<field name="content">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">wysiwyg</item>
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">content</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Content</item>
                    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/form/field</item>
                    <item name="wysiwyg" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">content</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                    <item name="rows" xsi:type="number">8</item>
                    <item name="wysiwygConfigData" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="is_pagebuilder_enabled" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                        <item name="toggle_button" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="height" xsi:type="string">200px</item>
                        <item name="add_variables" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_widgets" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_images" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="add_directives" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
    </field>
```

in frontend for print the data I am using template file

[image]

Comment: post your code...

Comment: In frontend layout I am using this to print the data of editor.
and it is working fine 
but after adding the data from Widget then it show html content
<?php echo $data['content']; ?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can check following solution
https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/how-to-filter-static-block-content-in-template-file-using-magento-2/

need prepare cms-content, convert variables to text.

like for email template.